# Why can't answers be favorited?

Tags: discussion, badges, bookmarks

I always favorite great questions , but I can't favorite an answer. If we can favorite good questions, why shouldn't we favorite great answers.

This can have two advantages for the site:

- We can have favorited answers by many users and we can realize how good our answers is.(favorited answer is more valuable than upvoted answers)
- Also we can have three or two badges for it ( **stellar answer**(gold badge):An answer favorited by 100 users  -  **favorite answer**(silver badge):An answer favorited with by 25 users)

Answer (score 2):

If you feel an answer is great please upvote it. That is why upvotes exist.

If you enjoy an answer very much, you can start a bounty on the question and award the bounty to that answer. Answers with bounties will show that it is well beloved!

Comment: You just suggested me what to do , when I enjoyed an answer.

Comment: Ok, basically you just upvote the answers you enjoy

Comment: And also with offering a bounty on a question and awarding this, I can't show and tell others how good this answer is.

Comment: Even if you favorite a question, no one will know who favorited it. However if you offer a bounty, it will definitely pull the attention to that post. People will want to see why that answer got bounty and so they will read it more often and the answer will get more upvotes. So basically it attracts more people.

Comment: So,why can I favorite question? If i can favorite question, I should can favorite answer. This is all the thing I want to say.

Comment: You favorite a question to follow it. You see that the question is good and you would be interested in knowing what answers it will get, you can favorite it. It helps you to follow that question and also bookmark it.

Comment: Basically you don't want to miss anything related to that question

Comment: Excellent, exactly what I wanted to know.

Comment: There is a potential difference though; you might like an answer (for educational purposes, interesting subject, nice presentation), while not being able to evaluate if it is correct. Personally, I'm hesitant to vote on answers if I cannot evalaute whether they are correct (at least partially so), and in those cases the ability to favorite an answer could be useful.

Answer (score 2):

This lack of a feature has been [discussed to death on the Meta SE forums](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2588/mark-answer-as-favorite-star/147592#147592).

In short: Jeff Atwood (one of the SE head developers) has [refused to add this feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/107790/278258) to the SE site, and this feature is unlikely to be added any time in the near future. As expected, it was downvoted to hell. Unfortunately for us, the bookmark (or favouriting the question itself) appears to be the best option for this for now.